# How to call a function in context of another thread?

Tags: winapi

I remember there was a way to do this, something similar to unix signals, but not so widely used. But can't remember the term. No events/mutexes are used: the thread is just interrupted at random place, the function is called and when it returns, the thread continues.

Comment: Are you sure it was a function in the context of another thread?  Windows makes it easy to run code in another process, but in another thread is something I don't ever remember seeing.

Comment: Please don't put tag information in your title. The tagging system here is very good at classifying things, and doesn't need help. :-) Please see [Should questions include "tags" in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/172661). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search `RtlRemoteCall`, it's an undocumented routine though. there's APC in Windows semantically similar to Unix signal, however APC requires target thread is in an alertable state to get delivered, it's not guaranteed this condition is always met

Comment: Just tried RtlRemoteCall. Apparently, if a thread is in non-alertable wait (synchronous ReadFile), the function is not called.

Answer (score 3):

Windows has [Asynchronous Procedure Calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which can call a function in the context of a specific thread.   APC's do not just interrupt a thread at a random place (that would be dangerous - the thread could be in the middle of writing to a file or obtaining a lock or in Kernel mode).  Instead an APC will be dispatched when the calling thread enters an alterable wait by calling a specific function (See the APC documentation).

If the reason that you need to call code in a specific thread is because you are interacting with the user interface, it would be more direct to [send](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644944%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) a window message to the window handle that you want to update.  Window messages are always processed in the thread that created the window.

Comment: +1, yup - PostMessage/SendMessage for GUI, else APC with alertable wait.