# How to execute a function on a specific thread id in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Is it possible I can invoke a function on a specific thread given the thread ID? I am currently on a different thread.

Comment: Sure. You can create a queue and put the functions you want called there and let the target thread read the queue and execute the functions. Certain frameworks have built-in support for it, like Windows.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Can you illustrate more on that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have some options here: [How to call a function in context of another thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750864/how-to-call-a-function-in-context-of-another-thread).

Answer (score 0):

You need cooperation from the target thread; for instance, the target thread has to execute a loop at the top of which it waits on some sort of message box. Through that message box you give it a message that contains the function to be called and the arguments to use. Through the same mechanism, the function can produce a reply containing the result of the call.

But you can't just make a random thread that is running arbitrary code call your function. Although, never say never. There are tricks like, for instance, asynchronous POSIX signals and such: send a signal to a thread, which inspects some datum that tells it to call a function. That is confounded by the limitations as to what can be safely done out of a signal handler.

In a debugger, you can stop all the threads, then "switch" to a particular one and evaluate expressions in its context, including function calls. That is also an approach that would be inadvisable to integrate into production code; you have no idea what state a stopped thread is in to be able to safely and reliably do anything in that thread.

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to make the worker threads execute based on tasks (functions),i.e you use a container to store functions you'd like the worker thread to execution, and the work thread's job is to execute functions in the container.

Here's an example, hope it helps.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;

void foo() {
    cout << "foo() is called" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
class TaskQueue {
    public:
        void enqueue(T&& task) {
            unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
            tasks.push_back(move(task));
            cv.notify_one();
        }
        bool empty() { unique_lock<mutex> l(m); return tasks.empty(); }
        void setStop() { stop = true; unique_lock<mutex> l(m); cv.notify_one(); }
        void run() {
            T t;
            while (!stop) {
                {
                    unique_lock<mutex> l(m);
                    cv.wait(l, [&] {return !tasks.empty() || stop;});
                    if (!tasks.empty()) {
                        t = move(tasks.front());
                        tasks.pop_front();
                    }
                    else 
                        return;
                }
                t();
            }
        }
    private:
        atomic<bool> stop = false;
        mutex m;
        condition_variable cv;
        list<T> tasks;
};

int main() {
    TaskQueue<function<void(void)>> taskq;
    thread t(&TaskQueue<function<void(void)>>::run, &taskq);
    taskq.enqueue(foo);
    taskq.enqueue(foo);
    taskq.enqueue(foo);
    while (!taskq.empty()) {}
    taskq.setStop();
    t.join();
}
```

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin The post you referenced to seems to have the original code edited, I don't understand your specific comments to that post without the context (and confusingly that OP claims deadlock still happens in the last comment). Maybe it's easier for you to elaborate your comments using this example.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin finally figured out a way to read the original code of that post, the bug is plain and simple -- the termination flag was not checked in the conditional variable wait condition and was only checked in the outer loop, surely there's a race condition. That's not the case here, though, could you elaborate how we can get a deadlock in this code? I haven't touched my code :-)

Comment: I see now, you do check `stop` while the mutex is held. And that makes using `std::atomic` for stop flag unnecessary since you have to lock the mutex to signal anyway.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin Please note that ```t();``` is executed outside the scope of lock, depending on the use case, you may want to check the termination flag cheaply before grabbing the mutex, which could cause contention with the producer thread. The main point of my code is to illustrate how to implement a task queue, and I'll leave it to OP to decide the trivial details.

Comment: I don't think that not having to grab the mutex on termination is a meaningful optimization the effects of which you'd be able to measure. Also, depending on where `stop` is checked it either grabs an item from the queue or not - inconsistent behaviour.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin As I said, meaningful or not depending on the situation -- this is a sample and I wrote it based on my experience. If you're certain people should never write such code, please feel free to make a proposal to cpp committee to make it an official cpp guideline. I'm sure the OP now gets the idea of writing a task queue, that is my main point. Regarding the "inconsistent behaviour", my only comment is that you do seem to be very assertive ;-) Instead of spending time criticizing other people's code, maybe you could provide your own 'correct' answer :)